# Excel table with automatic time and date

Tags: excel, ms-office

how to make a table with 7 columns A,B,C,D,E,F,H. Where if I enter Column C is protected and disabled. If Someone enter a text or number in Column A Example-A1 then the C1 should show the current time(system Time). Also note that other fields/Rows will be disabled until all the cells of Row 1 is filled. Can anyone help?
Hi i would like to know what should I do to get the system time in a protected field. Example:- If I enter anything in Column A will give the system time on Column B in the respective cell. What if the entire column B is protected?

Comment: I am a little confused... Are you just trying to protect cells C1:H1 to stop other users from editing? Is the purpose of C1 to log the date and time that something was entered into A1? Do you want the remaining cells to be editable after something has been entered in A1 but not before?

Comment: Yes you are Right. I want to stop users to edit the Column C. Also if a user is entering something in Column A , Cell 1, then the current system time should be shown in the 'Column C' - 'Cell 1'. the pointer / the selection should move from A, B to D.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but one of the best explanations I found for locking cells is here (Assuming you are using Excel 2013) https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/02/16/lock-unlock-cells-excel/

Comment: As far as entering data in one cell when another has data entered this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170379/excel-formula-which-places-date-time-in-cell-when-data-is-entered-in-another-cel