# is there any excel formula to record cell last change date?

Tags: excel, timestamp

I'm looking for a way to save the last change date of a cell in Excel without using the Worksheet_Change event.
for example define a formula like this:

```
=LastChangeDate(A22)
```

and when the cell A22 changed , current date show in target cell

Comment: No, you will have to use `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: Cannot do that without a macro.

Comment: @GSerg thanks for your reply . But I make a formula that seems to work fine without Worksheet_Change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a User Defined Function to do that but its is not completely tested.
Note two points before using this function :

1- this function shows result after you save document (ctrl+s) or change another cells

2-only change address of target cell and never change other parameters in this function

in fact we record last value of target cell in parameter of function

follow these steps :

1-open MSExcel and make new ".xlsm" file

2-press Alt+F11 to open VBA window

3-Make New Module

4-Copy this code to Module1 :

```
Public Function LogDate(CellAddress As String, OldValue As String, DisplayDate As String) As String

     Dim CellValue As String
     CellValue = Range(CellAddress).Value
     If CellValue = OldValue Then
        LogDate = DisplayDate
     Else
        Dim Address As String
        Address = Replace(CellAddress, "$", "")

        DisplayDate = Now
        Evaluate "ChangeFormula(""" + Application.Caller.Address(False, False) + """ , """ + Address + """ , """ + CellValue + """ , """ + DisplayDate + """)"
        
        LogDate = DisplayDate
     End If
End Function
 
Private Sub ChangeFormula(CurrentCellAddress As String, Address As String, CellValue As String, DisplayDate As String)
  Range(CurrentCellAddress).Formula = "=LogDate(CELL(""address""," & Address & "),""" & CellValue & """,""" & DisplayDate & """)"
End Sub
```

4-click on a cell "A2" and write this formula inside it :

```
=LogDate(CELL("address",A1),"","")
```

target cell address is "A1" dont change any parameter except "A1"

now when you change "A1" cell value , and save document(ctrl+s) or change other cells , "A2" Display date and time of "A1" changes .

Comment: You are using [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23437280/11683) to force Excel to do something it is not designed to do (i.e. allow sheet functions to change sheets). It is [not going to end well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52698777/11683). You are not supposed to change sheets from functions called from sheets.